# Detect a pattern within a string, extract all the substrings in which that pattern occurs and then modify it and replace it in its original position

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-re

```py
import re

input_text = "03:00 am hay 1  Entre la 1:30 y las 2:0, o 01:02 am  minuto y salimos, 19:30 pm salimos!! es importante llegar alla antes 20 :30 am, ya que 21:00 pm cierran algunos negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01 : 00 am, 1:00 am 1:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5: pm"
```

This is the regexp prototype to detect a pattern that encompasses the following substrings

```py
civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?'
civil_time_unit_list = list(map(re.findall(civil_time_pattern, input_text)))
```

the substrings it must be able to detect in the original input string: `["03:00 am", "1:30", "2:0", "01:02 am", "19:30 pm", "20 :30 am", "21:00 pm", "23:30 pm", "01 : 00 am", "1:00 am", "1:00 pm", ": p m", "1: pm", "5: pm"]`

This is the **conversion process that must have each one of the substrings** ( **hh**:**mm** **am** or **pm** ) that it detects within the `input_string`. One of the problems with this code is how to apply these replacements only in cases where the previous regex is true.

```py
#Block of code that should receive the substring, chunk it and try to correct it, then later replace the corrected version in the original string
    if (If the pattern is met...  ):
        try:
            hh = civil_time_unit_list[0][0]
            if (hh == ""): hh = "00"
        except IndexError: hh = "00"

        try:
            mm = civil_time_unit_list[0][1]
            if (mm == ""): mm = "00"
        except IndexError: mm = "00"

        try:
            am_pm = civil_time_unit_list[0][2]
            if (am_pm == ""):
                if (int(hh) >= 0 and int(hh) < 12): am_pm = "am"
                elif (int(hh) >= 12 and int(hh) < 24): am_pm = "pm"
            else:
                #If it says pm, the indication pm will be prioritized over the hour that is indicated
                #But if it says am the time will be prioritized over the indication of am
                if (am_pm == "am"):
                    if (int(hh) >= 12 and int(hh) < 24): am_pm = "pm"
                    else: pass
                elif (am_pm == "pm"):
                    if (int(hh) >= 0 and int(hh) < 12): hh = str( int(hh) + 12 )
                    else: pass
        except IndexError:
            if (int(hh) >= 0 and int(hh) < 12): am_pm = "am"
            elif (int(hh) >= 12 and int(hh) < 24): am_pm = "pm"

        #Add "0" in front, if the substring is not 2 characters long
        if (len(hh) < 2): hh = "0" + hh
        if (len(mm) < 2): mm = "0" + mm

        output = hh + ":" + mm + " " + am_pm
        output = output.strip()
```

One of the possible problems is that we do not know how many times that pattern will appear, so I do not know how many times it would have to be extracted and therefore I do not know how many substrings I will have to send to the correction and replacement process, and I also have to consider that the same replacement can occur 2 times (or more).

```py
print(repr(input_text)) #You should now be able to print the original string but with all the replacements already done.
```

And this is the **correct output** that I need, as you can see the previous process has been applied on each of the patterns **hh**:**mm** **am** or **pm**

```py
input_text = "03:00 am hay 1  Entre la 01:30 am y las 02:00 am, o 01:02 am  minuto y salimos, 19:30 pm salimos!! es importante llegar alla antes 20:30 pm, ya que 21:00 pm cierran algunos negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 13:00 pm, 00:00 am, 13:00 pm  05:00 pm"
```

Comment: [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: @Matiiss was the first thing that occurred to me, but it might be useful to combine it with a `re.findall()`, I'm not sure, because you also have to be able to extract part of the value to place it inside the process that performs the replacement. Since it must be checked if it is am or pm, perhaps using a `re.group()` is also necessary for this.

Comment: read the docs and you'll find out that `re.sub` can take a function that will return the new string that will be put in place of the matched one

Comment: What I'm wondering about is whether re.sub is useful for extracting parts of the main chain and then passing them to the check-and-replace process, and then replacing them. I've already seen the documentation, but how to do that depends a lot on how the algorithm is structured.

Comment: `re.sub` will pass to the given function the matched part of the string, just enclose the entire pattern in parentheses and the first group will be the entire matched string, then run it through your algorithm and return the fixed string, it will then be used to replace what was matched

Comment: @Matiiss I think that the most complex part of doing this is once a pattern has been identified, being able to extract `am_pm = civil_time_unit_list[0][2]`, `am_pm = civil_time_unit_list[0][1]` and `am_pm = civil_time_unit_list[0][2]`

Comment: I don't even know what `civil_time_unit_list` contains, your code has a bunch of undefined names

Comment: @Matiiss I used the pattern called `civil_time_pattern` in a `re.findall()` method.  `civil_time_unit_list = list(map(re.findall(civil_time_pattern, input_text)))` . But I'm not getting good results with that, since I just want to return a list of lists, and I don't know how to pass that to the conversion code, and then replace back into the original string.

Comment: by using `re.sub`, it will go over that string, and for every single match call the function you passed to `re.sub` as an argument and it will call that function and pass to it the match, then you can just convert it how you need and return how it should be and it will get replaced, I don't think you fully understand how `re.sub` works, it's the only thing from `re` you need to use really (could also use `re.compile` for the pattern but whatever)

Comment: also why do you keep am and pm if you convert to military time?

Comment: @Matiiss I am not referring exactly to military time, but from 00:00 to 11:59 is considered **am** time, and then from 12:00 to 23:59 is considered **pm** time. That is why I need to extract the hours, since they are used to evaluate if it is a time in the pm range or if it is a time in the am range.

Comment: I'm saying that if you have anything above _12:00_, it should no longer have _am_ or _pm_ indication, you can either have say _13:00_ or _1:00 pm_, you can't really have _13:00 pm_, that makes no sense and if I tried to make sense I'd say that _13:00 pm_ is the same as _1:00 pm the next day_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC this is what you want, replace all matched strings by that matched string converted to some other string, you can easily just do it with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) by giving it the function that will handle the conversion using the matched group and return it back to be used as the replacement:

```
input_text = "03:00 am hay 1  Entre la 1:30 y las 2:0, o 01:02 am  minuto y salimos, 19:30 pm salimos!! es importante llegar alla antes 20 :30 am, ya que 21:00 pm cierran algunos negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01 : 00 am, 1:00 am 1:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5: pm"
civil_time_pattern = re.compile(r"(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?")


def convert(match):
    hh = match.group(1) or "00"
    mm = match.group(2) or "00"

    am_pm = match.group(3)
    if not am_pm:
        if 0 <= int(hh) < 12:
            am_pm = "am"
        elif 12 <= int(hh) < 24:
            am_pm = "pm"
    # If it says pm, the indication pm will be prioritized over the hour that is indicated
    # But if it says am the time will be prioritized over the indication of am
    if am_pm == "am":
        if 12 <= int(hh) < 24:
            am_pm = "pm"
    elif am_pm == "pm":
        if 0 <= int(hh) < 12:
            hh = str(int(hh) + 12)

    # Add "0" in front, if the substring is not 2 characters long
    hh = hh.zfill(2)
    mm = mm.zfill(2)

    output = f"{hh}:{mm}"
    return output


result = civil_time_pattern.sub(convert, input_text)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot, the only problem I found was when `hh` is nothing, for example `input_text = ":00 am hay 1 "`, and you get as output this `"result = ":00:00 am hay 01:00"`,  the `":00:00"` is wrong, it should be `"00:00 am"`.

Comment: that's possibly caused by the lack of leading space there, it should work fine if you had `" :00 am"`, maybe